# Swift: Sorting Core Data child entities on fetch based on Date

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, core-data

## Introduction

I'm making a calendar app in which I store events using Core Data.

Its composed of: `DateKey` as the parent (with a one-to-many relationship) to `CalendarEventModel`. The concept is that `DateKey` holds a yyyy-dd-MM date string and all events that occur that day are added as a child to that `DateKey` as `CalendarEventModel` in a NSOrderedSet. (I'm using Class Definition, none of the entities are abstract.). CalendarEventModel being the entity containing information about one calendar event.

**What I try to accomplish**

Everything works as intended except that I can't sort my fetched results. When I fetch the DateKeys relevant for the current Calendar I simply can't get them to sort like this:

I want to sort the CalendarEventModel in each DateKey after the CalendarEventModels attribute `startDate` in ascending order ($0.startDate < $1.startDate). Then have the CalendarEventModels marked `isAllDay = false` before those with `isAllDay = true`.

**Issue/Question**

- I've put some clarifications in comment in the code below.
- I can't get NSSortDescriptor to work properly ( my attempt is commented in the code below
- I've read about NSOrderedSet which the `calendarEvents` attribute of DateKey is, but I haven't found out how to use it for my sorting criteria.

*How would you solve this sorting?*
Let me know if more information is needed.

**My code**

```
fileprivate func loadEventsFromCoreData() {

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy dd MM"
    let startDate = Date()
    var predicatesForFetch : [NSPredicate] = []
    var dateStringArray : [String] = []
    var fetchResultsArray : [DateKey]?

    for num in 0...9 {
        let newDate = startDate.add(TimeChunk(seconds: 0, minutes: 0, hours: 0, days: num, weeks: 0, months: 0, years: 0))
        let datePredicate = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate)
        dateStringArray.append(datePredicate)
        predicatesForFetch.append(NSPredicate(format: "dateInfo == %@", datePredicate))
    }
    setupSectionArray(eventArray: dateStringArray)

    // I'm getting the correct DateKeys and their events.

    let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicatesForFetch)
    let eventFetch : NSFetchRequest<DateKey> = DateKey.fetchRequest()
    eventFetch.predicate = compoundPredicate

    // I've tried specifying this sortDescriptor and added it to the eventFetch: 
    //   let descriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "calendarEvents", ascending: true) { ($0 as! CalendarEventModel).startDate!.compare(($1 as! CalendarEventModel).startDate!) }
    //   let sortDescriptors = [descriptor]
    //   eventFetch.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

        do {
            fetchResultsArray = try coreDataContext.fetch(eventFetch)

        } catch {
            print("Core Data initial fetch failed in Calendar Controller: \(error)")
        }

    guard fetchResultsArray != nil else { return }

    // Xcode doesn't recognize the .sort() function which does not have a return value... and I don't think its a good idea to use the return function at all since I will have to delete all children and re add the sorted for each fetch.

    for eventArray in fetchResultsArray! {
        eventArray.calendarEvents?.sorted(by: { ($0 as! CalendarEventModel).startDate!.compare(($1 as! CalendarEventModel).startDate!) == .orderedAscending })
        eventArray.calendarEvents?.sorted { ($0 as! CalendarEventModel).isAllDay && !($1 as! CalendarEventModel).isAllDay }

    }

    events = fetchResultsArray!
}
```

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes:

- Basically you cannot sort dates in string format `"yyyy dd MM"`, either use `"yyyy MM dd"` or – highly recommended – `Date` type.
- You cannot sort a relationship in place. To-many relationships are `Set`s which are unordered. By the way declare the relationship as native `Set<CalendarEventModel>` rather than unspecified `NSSet` and as non-optional.
- Don't use a compound predicate, use **one** predicate and don't fetch `DateKey` records, fetch `CalendarEventModel` records with predicate `dateKey.dateInfo >= startDate && dateKey.dateInfo <= endDate` and add there the two sort descriptors.

Fetching filtered and sorted records once is much more efficient than get the relationship items and sort them *manually*.

**Edit:**

To get midnight of today and + 9 days use

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let now = Date()
let nowPlus9Days = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 9, to: now)!
let startDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: now)
let endDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: nowPlus9Days)
```

This code fetches all sorted `CalendarEventModel` in the date range and groups the array to a `[Date : [CalendarEventModel]]` dictionary

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateKey.dateInfo >= %@ && dateKey.dateInfo <= %@", startDate as CVarArg, endDate as CVarArg)
let sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "startDate", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "isAllDay", ascending: true)]

let eventFetch : NSFetchRequest<CalendarEventModel> = CalendarEventModel.fetchRequest()
eventFetch.predicate = predicate
eventFetch.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
do {
    let fetchResultsArray = try coreDataContext.fetch(eventFetch)
    let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: fetchResultsArray, by: {$0.startDate})

} catch {
    print("Core Data initial fetch failed in Calendar Controller: \(error)")
}
```

Don't execute *good* code after the `catch` block. Put all *good* code in the `do` scope after the fetch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes sense. But I'm saving the CalendarEventModel entities in the DateKey with dateInfo equal to the CalendarEventModel.startDate. Since I need the `[CalendarEventModel]` for each day to use them in different sections of my calendar view I need them in a `[Date : [CalendarEventModel]]` type. So, to recap, instead would you suggest I'll fetch `CalendarEventModel` records and store them in a variable in my view controller of type: `[Date : [CalendarEventModel]]` where the Date is supposed to represent the `DateKey.dateInfo of the `[CalendarEventModel]` parent?

Comment: Also 1. Where/How do I declare the relationship like that  `Set<CalendarEventModel>`? 2. Would you mind writing an example of the NSPredicate? I need to fetch all CalendarEventModel records for ”todays date” and the next 9 days. And I can't figure out how to format it.

Comment: Once again the model cannot work anyway if the date string format is `yyyy dd MM` because it's not sortable. I highly recommend to use `Date` rather than `String`. You can change the `Set` type in the `NSManagedObject` subclass.

Comment: Yes, I took your advice and I've changed the `dateInfo` to be of type `Date` instead. Ah, of course, thanks. But I'm still stuck at formatting that predicate, on how to fetch CalendarEventModel objects for the correct dates ( `Date()` and 9 days forward), as well as formatting the NSSortDescriptor. Would appreciate just a little push in formatting those.

Comment: Works as it should. Thank you!